# What is the best way to bounce a value between two limits?

Tags: java

What is the best way to increment and then to decrement a value between two limits by a variable step. For instance: start with "0", stop at "10", step by "1": 0, 1, 2 ... 9, 10, 9, 8 ... 2, 1, 0, 1, 2 ... and so far (like a yoyo).

My solution for this is:

```
public void something() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        float counter = 0;
        int step = 5;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (counter >= 100)
                    step = -5;
                if (counter <= 0)
                    step = 5;

                counter += step;
                // do something ...

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Best in what sense?  What's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: You can do `step = -step` once the counter gets to one of the limit bounds. Apart of that, what's your exact problem?

Comment: I would have a `upperLimit` and a `lowerLimit` and replace the value of the step when I reach those.

Comment: Note: Don't instantiate a new Thread manually. Rather use the utility classes from the java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: better int counter, no float counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest encapsulating the behaviour in its own class. Something like:

```
public class Yoyo {
  private final int from;
  private final int to;

  private int current;
  private int step;

  public Yoyo(int from, int to, int step) {
    if (step > to - from || to <= from) throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid arguments");
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.current = from - step;
    this.step = step;
  }

  public synchronized int next() {
    if (current + step > to || current + step < from) step = -step;
    return current += step;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Yoyo y = new Yoyo(1, 10, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) System.out.println(y.next());
  }
}
```

Comment: you just forget to define current in the constructor, like this.current = from - step;

Comment: @danny Good catch - my example only works when `from` is 1. Will amend.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to work fine, but you can also use two for loops:

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
    counter = i;
    // Sleep here
}
for(int i=9;i>=0;i--) {
    counter = i;
    // Sleep here
}
```